# How could I remove the last space character from a string in c#?

Tags: c#

I split text from a text file and I have to compare 2 strings, one from a textbox and the other one from a text file from a specific line. That string from text has a space at the end and the comparison is always wrong.
Here is the code. Thank you!

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Random r = new Random();

    t = r.Next(1,30);
    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("NomenA1.txt");
    cuv = sr.ReadToEnd().Split('\n');

    string original = cuv[t];

    Random num = new Random();

    // Create new string from the reordered char array.
    string rand = new string(original.ToCharArray().
        OrderBy(s => (num.Next(2) % 2) == 0).ToArray());
    textBox2.Text = rand;
    button1.Visible = false;
    button2.Visible = true;

}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    button1.Visible = false;
    string a =Convert.ToString(textBox1.Text.ToString());
    string b = cuv[t];

    if (a == b)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Corect");
        button1.Visible = true;
        button2.Visible = false;
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Mai incearca"); button1.Visible = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: [String.Trim(char array)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d4tt83f9%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [String.Trim()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t97s7bs3%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Are you sure it's a whitespace character on the end? You are splitting on '\n', but many machines use '\r\n' to indicate a new line. If your text file is using '\r\n' then all of your data in the `cuv` array is actually ending in '\r', not in a whitespace. This would also cause your `if (a == b)` to fail.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `Regex` to remove all last space:

```
string s = "name    ";
string a = Regex.Replace(s, @"\s+$", "");
```

or `Trim()` function for all both end space:

```
string s = " name   ";
string a = s.Trim();
```

or if you want to remove only one space from the end:

```
string s = "name ";
string a = Regex.Replace(s, @"\s$", "");
```

Comment: Your regex removes **1 or many** trailing white space(s), not just the last.

Comment: yes it remove all space at the end, I think OP is asking that

Comment: OP mentioned "the **last** character" and "txt has **a** space at the end".

Answer (score 3):

> How could I remove the last character in a string

```
var s = "Some string ";
var s2 = s.Substring(0, s.Length - 1);
```

Alternatively a general solution is usually

```
var s3 = s.Trim(); // Remove all whitespace at the start or end
var s4 = s.TrimEnd(); // Remove all whitespace at the end
var s5 = s.TrimEnd(' '); // Remove all spaces from the end
```

Or a very specific solution

```
// Remove the last character if it is a space
var s6 = s[s.Length - 1] == ' ' ? s.Substring(0, s.Length - 1) : s;
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried .Trim()

```
String myStringA="abcde "; 
String myStringB="abcde"; 

if (myStringA.Trim()==myStringB) 
{
  Console.WriteLine("Matches"); 
} 
else 
{
  Console.WriteLine("Does not match");    
}
```

Comment: I didn't downvote anything to the best of my knowlege

Comment: Someone downvoted your answer, I was just wondering if they could explain why. (Doesn't do much good for everyone else if they never share).

Answer (score -1):

What about :

```
string s = "name ";
string a = s.Replace(" ", "");
```

That seems pretty simple to me, right?

Comment: thanks for your simple solution. But if you want to remove all space in a text you can use this solution.